# Polymer. After dom-repeat, child offsetLeft returns an invalid value

Tags: polymer-1.0, dom-repeat

I execute a dom-repeat to fill a horizontal flexbox with some items. In dom-change event i'm trying to get the offsetLeft of one of the flexbox childs created, in order to scroll to it to make it visible.

My problem is that, offsetLeft always returns a value corresponding to the first child, no matters what child i ask for. It only happens, after recently execute dom-repeat. If a execute the same code when on-tap a child, it works fine.

Anyone has any suggestion to solve the problem, or other strategy to get the same result ?

Thanks a lot in advance

Comment: Can you add some code as well

Comment: This JSBin http://jsbin.com/vayacaw/edit?html,output works well, the difference with my problem is that i load data at execution time